# Running start.microprofile.io demo on Netbeans 11.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, microservices, payara, microprofile

I am new in the Microservices world. I have read a lot o materials but still not able to run my first app.
So I have generated a demo from https://start.microprofile.io with the following configuration:

MicroProfile Version: MP2.1
MicroProfile Server : Payara Micro
All 8 specifications.

I was able to import the demo in netbeans 11.1 and I have installed Payara full 191.

My question is: what is the next step? What should I do to run the demo?
Any help to get more closer to the world of Microservices with Eclipse MicroProfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start.microprofile.io will have created a Maven project for you.

Within the root directory of the project, there should be a `readme.md` file that explains what you have created.

You can build the project with `mvn clean package` and then run it with `java -jar target/demo-microbundle.jar` (the name `demo` may change depending on your project name).

You can then access the sample app by going to `http://localhost:8080/index.html`

Since this is a microprofile application, you do not necessarily need to deploy it to Payara full. You can run this application as a standalone jar.

Comment: Thanks a lot @David-Salter. In fact, each project have a `readme.md` file that explains how to use the project. Just one additional question: is it possible to run `java -jar target/demo-microbundle.jar` from Netbeans 11.1?

Comment: You can run the application from NetBeans by right clicking on the project and selecting "Run", or by selecting the "Run" button in the toolbar.

Comment: With the run command directly from Netbeans, Payara is started but not the app. On the web browser I get `HTTP Status 404`. When I run `java -jar target/demo-microbundle.jar` everything is just fine.